# Adding a If statement Inside If Function

Tags: jquery

Can somebody explain to me,how to add If inside If I mean something like that:

```js
 $(window).resize(function(){
   if ($(window).width()<1000)
   {
    $('.search-trigger').on('click',function(){
     if($('.search-overlay').hasClass('show'))
      $('.search-overlay').removeClass('show');
        }
        else
        {
         $('.search-overlay').addClass('show');
        }
    });
   }
 });
```

If browser window is under 1000px ,turn on other search-menu style (full overlay search page), when click on search button. I'm using this code at the moment and got a error in console,which is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

after argument list.
Please if somebody can explain to me how to add If into If,to fix my search menu.THANKS !!

Comment: Fix your indentation and trace your brackets. There is a syntax error in your code.

Comment: FYI - you need to unbind the click handler before assigning a new one. This will add a new handler every resize event and that fires pretty often when resizing a window. Nothing good will come of that.

Comment: The second **if** needs an open **{**. I want to echo @asawyer comment.    You don't want to continuously add *click* handlers (thousands of them) when your window resizes.

Comment: Well thanks! That was for the error,but function isnt working ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var smallerThanThousand = false;
    $(window).resize(function(){
            if ($(window).width()<1000)
            {
                smallerThanThousand = true;
            }else{
                smallerThanThousand = false;
            }
    });
    $('.search-trigger').on('click',function(){
        If(smallerThanThousand === true){
            if($('.search-overlay').hasClass('show')){
                $('.search-overlay').removeClass('show');
            }
            else
            {
                $('.search-overlay').addClass('show');
            }
        }
    });
```